# RSpec around() block behaves different from a before() + after()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, apartment-gem

I'm using the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) to manage a multi-tenant Rails app.

*Side Note:* If you're unfamiliar with the gem, switching apartments is simply switching the schema used on the Postgres DB back-end. You change apartment tenants with `Apartment::Tenant.switch!(apartment)`

I have several tests that test behavior under the context of a certain apartment tenant. To do that, I use the below setup (example shown for Controller specs)

```
RSpec.describe MyController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    # Some global before() setup
  end

  context "foo apartment" do

    ### Option 1 - Using the around() hook
    around(:each) do |example|
      begin
        Apartment::Tenant.switch!("foo")
        example.run
      ensure
        Apartment::Tenant.switch!("public")
      end
    end

    ### Option 2 - Independent before() + after() hooks
    before(:each) { Apartment::Tenant.switch!("foo") }
    after(:each) { Apartment::Tenant.switch!("public") }


    it "tests that the foo apartment is being used" do
      expect(Apartment::Tenant.current).to eq("foo")
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, there are two approaches to setting up the test. One uses the `around()` hook and the other does the same thing, but independently uses the `before()` and `after()` hooks.

I'd imagine that both approaches are equivalent and interchangeable. But surprisingly only Option 2 actually works.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Does the `around()` block run in some different order than the `before()` block?

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/around-hooks), `around`  accomplishes a similar goal as `before` and `after`.  But "`around` hooks do not share state with the example the way `before` and `after` hooks do."  Check out the docs; there are a bunch of examples in there as well.

Comment: I think that answers it, I missed it when I read through the docs. Thanks! If you want to move your comment to an answer I'd be happy to mark it as answered.

Comment: Also note that your  #some global before() setup  block will actually get run inside the around block -- which is most likely the cause here, since I'm assuming that global setup block resets the Tenant

Answer (score 3):

An around(:each) block will wrap all before(:each) blocks (even those defined at an outer scope level).  Because of this with your option 1 around block you're getting the following behavior

```
around_before
  global before() setup block
  example runs
around_after
```

If your global setup block sets a default tenant or anything it would be overwriting what you're doing in your around block

with option 2 you get

```
global before() setup block
before block
example runs
after block
```